# Objects in DataGrid not firing ListChanged event in BindingList they are in

Tags: wpf, datagrid, listchanged

I have read pretty much all Stackoverflow questions about `DataGrid, BindingList<T>` and `ListChanged` and still have no answer.

I have an object called `Invoice : INotifyPropertyChanged`, that has a `BindingList<InvoiceLine> : INotifyPropertyChanged` that consists of number of `InvoiceLine : INotifyPropertyChanged` objects.

Now when in the `DataGrid` that is bound to the `BindableList<InvoiceLine>` I change one of the properties of a `InvoiceLine` a `PropertyChanged` event is fired but `ListChanged` event is not fired on the `BindableList<InvoiceLine>`.

InvoiceLines is initialized like this:

```
this.InvoiceLines = new BindingList<InvoiceLine>();
this.InvoiceLines.ListChanged += new System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventHandler(InvoiceLines_ListChanged);
this.InvoiceLines.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
this.InvoiceLines.AllowEdit = true;
```

Comment: It always helpst to create a StackOverflow question. I figured it out, as dumb as it is, I actually was working with a copy of the collection and I didn't notice :D.